# How did the Earth survive Overgirl's supernova?

Tags: dc, arrowverse, legends-of-tomorrow, crisis-on-earth-x

In the Arrowverse cross-over event *Crisis on Earth-X*, when Overgirl went supernova she was dangerously close to the Earth.

A supernova at that point could obliterate even entire solar system including the Sun. How did the Earth survive?

I don't exactly remember who, but Gideon or Earth X's Waverider's AI or someone sciency even mentioned energy of Overgirl approaching [Chandrasekhar Limit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chandrasekhar_limit). So, I have reasons to take *Supernova* word literally.

Comment: I think it was Mr. Terrific, actually. Not that any of it made a lick of sense.

Comment: Overgirl's explosion hardly looks like it was at the level of a *real* supernova, ie a whole star exploding. Maybe a nuclear explosion at best. Hardly a world destroyer. I think the term "supernova" was just an expression to describe "a really big boom".

Comment: Side question: how did Arrowverse's Kara avoid the same fate?  It was about her body absorbing too much sunlight radiation.

Comment: @jhpace1 Just call her *Supergirl* or Earth-1's Kara.